# Count Chars in a String Java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, count

Hi I have a problem in my code, I have to count the variables used in an expression and when two or more variables are same it should be counted as 1. For example, a+ab = the total number of variable used: 2. The problem is when I inputted a+a =total number of variable used: 2.
Here's my code:

```
public void simplify(String strexp){
    int ex =strexp.length();

    for (int a=0;a<=ex-1;a++){
        if(a==0)
        {
        if (Character.isLetter(strexp.charAt(a)))
        {
        b++;
       }


        }
        else{
        for(int c=0;c<=a-1;c++){
              if (Character.isLetter(strexp.charAt(c))==Character.isLetter(strexp.charAt(a)))
              {

                System.out.println("equal");
                break;
              }
              else if (Character.isLetter(strexp.charAt(c))!=Character.isLetter(strexp.charAt(a)))
              {
             //if(c==a-1)
              //{
               b++;
               System.out.println("nomatch");
           //  }
               }
        }
        }
        }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b);
    }
```

Comment: You can use regular expression for finding all variables and then pass through some array unique function or whatever.

Comment: Does `ab` and `AB` count as equal?

Comment: Which one do you want to count: the number of variables or the number of characters? I can name a variable with one or more characters; for example: a, variable, ab, a1

Comment: Since your example includes `a + ab` which gives its total number variables of two(2). So, I assume each variable can be more than one character in length.

Comment: Sorry, your title is so misleading; it is different from what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list to count the total amount of variables

```
public static int simplify(String strexp) {
    int length = strexp.length();

    List<Character> usedVariables = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = strexp.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c) && !usedVariables.contains(c)) {
            usedVariables.add(c);
        }
    }

    return usedVariables.size();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(simplify("x + b = d"));
    System.out.println(simplify("x + x = a"));
    System.out.println(simplify("x + x = x / 2"));
}
```

This prints out

```
3
2
1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help,list is a great help

Comment: @AlvinPulido, pleasure, you can also vote up if you like an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a char array,add those to a map where the key is the char and the value its variable count.

```
import java.util.*;

    class Main

{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String yourString = "UNDERSTAND";

        Map<Character, Integer> count = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (char c : yourString.toCharArray()) {
            if (count.containsKey(c)) {
                count.put(c, (int) count.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                count.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Comment: The `Map` is unnecessary for his case, the count value is not needed in order to compute how many unique characters there are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of what variables you have seen. A way to do this might be to use a `Set<char>`. Whenever you see a character, add it to the set. The number of unique operators will be the number of characters in the set.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to follow at such low level. Why not to use Regular Expressions to find all the matches and then build a set of unique ones?

The title is misleading. The task is more like lexical token counting. It is one step higher than simple character.

Answer (score 0):

How about this *one-liner*?

```
String complexExpression = "a + a*2 (2*a + b - 34)/2 + 3*c";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(complexExpression.split("[+*()-/\\d\\s&&[^a-z]]+")));

System.out.println(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(complexExpression.split("[+*()-/\\d\\s&&[^a-z]]+"))).size());
```

The above code prints the below for me:

```
[a, a, a, b, c]
3
```

Of course, I don't recommend doing the `split` operation multiple times with the same pattern.

Comment: You answer is correct as it takes into account variables with one or more characters in size: for example an expression `"ab + ab*2 (2*ab + ba - 34)/2 + 3*c"` gives an array of `[ab, ab, ab, ba, c]` with the unique variables count of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something:

```
public class DistinctCharCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "a+ab+abc+abcd";

        HashSet<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();        
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
            charSet.add(s.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Distinct Char Count : " + charSet.size());
    }
}
```